# Find the coefficient of $x^{4}$ from $(1+x)^{1/3}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, taylor-expansion

> Find the coefficient of $x^{4}$ from $(1+x)^{1/3}$

Should I use the formula $C(n,k) = n!/[k!(n-k)!]$? And what is the solution of this problem?

Comment: Do you know [Newton's generalized binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem)?

Comment: This can also be done with a truncated Taylor expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the expression as $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{\frac{1}{3}}{k} x^k$ and expand the Binomial coefficient. If you feel intimidated by the fraction, just set $\frac{1}{3}=\alpha$ and use the expansion formula:
$$
\binom{\alpha}{k} = \alpha(\alpha-1)(\alpha-2) \ldots \frac{1}{k!}
$$
and plug in back $\frac{1}{3}$. Can you handle from here?

Comment: yes TY, my result is -10/243 x^4. hope i did well ;)